# Как вставить данные в БД MySQL с динамично сформированного javascript-файла?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, база-данных, dom

Здравствуйте. Возникла такая ситуация. Нужно вставить данные в БД с javascript-файла. При этом JS-файл генерируется при двойном клике (делаю расширение для Firefox - перевод слова). Также есть сайт на PHP, который выводит данные из этой БД. Каким образом можно передать данные сайту или БД MySQL с javascript-файла?

JS-файл (часть):

```
    var coords = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
    var dictDiv = $("<div class='dict' style='display: none;'>");
    var engDiv = $('<div class="eng list"></div>');
    var rusDiv = $('<div class="rus list"></div>');

    engDiv.html(dictResult).appendTo(dictDiv);
    rusDiv.html(rusWords).appendTo(dictDiv);

    dictDiv.offset({top:coords[1], left:coords[0]});
    dictDiv.appendTo('body');

    dictDiv.on('mousedown', function () {
        var popupString = $(this).text();
        var popupArray = popupString.split(' ');
        var popupTranslate = '';

        $(rusDiv).on('mouseup', 'div', function () {
            popupTranslate = $(this).text();
            popupTranslate = popupTranslate.split(' ');

            var outputArray = popupArray.splice(0, 2);
            //этот масив нужно отправить в БД
            var result = outputArray.concat(popupTranslate);
       });
    });
```

массив выглядит так (пример): `["code", "kəʊd", "код", "сущ"]`

Comment: эм, `ajax`? Ищите на просторах. Очень много информации об этом